# SQL Server 2008 Express Management Studio connects to database from LAN but using same connection string vb.net application fails to connect

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I developed an application using vb.net that connects to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database (Hospital) through LAN, from a client PC.

SQL Server 2008 Express Management Studio successfully connects to the database (Hospital), but using the same connection string, my vb.net application fails to connect.

My connection string is:

```
"Data Source=TCP:192.168.1.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Hospital;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=1111"
```

What is the problem? Can anybody help me to solve that?

Comment: According to connectionstrings.com, that's not how you connect via an IP address: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Answer (score 0):

First create a ODBC connection.
Then follow this connection string:
Data Source="SERVERNAME";Initial Catalog="DATABASE NAME";User ID="USERNAME";Password="PASSWORD"; 
IT should Work